# Shipping OS-specific binaries in an IntelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

I am evaluating the creation of an IntelliJ IDEA plugin which would ship OS-specific binaries, for macOS, Linux and Windows.

The binaries are fairly large, so I don't want to ship binaries for the 3 OS in the same plugin archive. Is it possible to create OS-specific zip archives for an IntelliJ plugin?

Comment: Are you shipping yourself (private plugin) or through the jetbrains repository (public plugin)?

Comment: The plan is to ship through a private repository by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to make 3 different binaries for the one plugin.

Different approaches you can take:

1. 3 different plugins. Shared code can be put in a different code module
2. The plugin downloads the binary upon startup from a private server (ftp / nexus)
3. Install the binaries separately, and have the plugin find the binaries via an environment variable

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I am leaning toward option 2 at the moment, I am building a proof-of-concept to validate this is doable.